# Django Finite State Machine and FSMKeyField - saving forms

Tags: python, django

I have implemented django-fsm's FSMKeyField [as documented](https://github.com/kmmbvnr/django-fsm#foreign-key-constraints-support):

```
class ClaimState(models.Model):

    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label
```

and have populated the ClaimState model with states via fixture, and am using an FSMKeyField pointer from another model:

```
class Claim(models.Model):
    state = FSMKeyField(ClaimState, default='new')
    ...
```

The foreign key works fine from a Django shell - I can do:

```
s = ClaimState.objects.first()
Claim.objects.create(state=s)
```

No problem. But when I try to save a claim from the Django Admin or from my own form, I get the error:

```
claim state instance with id <ClaimState: Rejected> does not exist.
```

If I view source, I can see that the dropdown values are the PKs, so it's not clear why it's treating the whole object as if it were the ID.

Not sure what's causing this or the best way to solve?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this same issue today and resolved it by specifying a custom Form for the model's admin and overriding the clean function for the `state` property.

In your case, this might look something like:

```python
class ClaimAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean_state(self):
        return self.cleaned_data["state"].id


@admin.register(Claim)
class ClaimAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = ClaimAdminForm
```

Comment: Thanks Matt. Yeah, that was going to be my next step (overriding clean and the form), but since the error was surprising, I thought either there was a bug or I had done something wrong. Still not sure I understand why it requires using strings as keys, or why it hides labels (you can't do myinstance.state.label). But at least this gets forms working. Cheers.